# Complex form widgets in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

I am looking for good helper libraries to generate a rather complex form in Django.

- Dynamic field dependencies: Say if option a is selected certain fields are shown/hidden and subset of these are mandatory depending on option selection.
- Add more: On clicking "Add more" button that clones some widget.

This is something which ToscaWidgets is capable of handle.

- http://toscawidgets.org/documentation/tw.dynforms/tutorial.html#growing
- [Some working ToscaWidgets Demos](http://toscawidgets.org/documentation/tw.dynforms/widgets/index.html#module-tw.dynforms.widgets)

Currently I am managing this with some jquery code however not completely satisfied. And sadly cant use ToscaWidgets for some reason.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a little more I found one solution. [django-dynamic-formset](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) based on django formsets solves the purpose. Impressive work

PS: Will try to add some screenshots later.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a heavily customized `Formset` to make a rather complicated form with complicated user permission dependencies. This involved subclassing `django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet`, overriding `__init__`, `add_fields`, `is_valid`, and `save`, and of course using a customized `Form`. The end-product was a bit hairy, but I'm still able to understand and modify it after 6 months or so.

I didn't make use of the Formset ability to work with adding and subtracting subforms, but this should meet your needs.

Documentation at: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/formsets/